# cloudformation lambda function upload from s3 deployment package structure issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I am using cloudformation to create my lambda function. I have opted to pull the code from S3.

However, it appears to create a nested structure when the lambda function gets created, and I am unable to import my packages unless I move the `lambda` and associated library packages up to the root level of the lambda function.

Cloudformation value for code section:

```
  Code:
    S3Bucket: youll_never_guess-bucket-12345
    S3Key: python_data_collector.zip
```

How it appears in lambda, aws console:

[image]

Full path for handler in console:
I've tried: `python_data_collector/lambda.lambda_handler` and `python_data_collector.lambda.lambda_handler`

Error message:

```
Unable to import module 'python_data_collector/lambda': No module named 'requests'"
```

Answer (score 0):

The Python dependencies should reside at the root level of you lambda deployment package. You can indeed point to a nested file as the entry point of your function, but this does not change the dependency behaviour of your function.

However, the structure of your lambda code has nothing to do with where your zip file is located in the S3 bucket. Presumably, when you are creating the zip file, you are adding a folder at the root level which contains the code & dependencies. You should not have that extra folder in the zip file and simply put the code (nested or not) and the dependencies (not nested) at the root of you zip package. Lambda will simply unzip the file and place the contents as is, in your lambda function.

Comment: The zip folder in question, python_data_collector, has all of the dependencies and lambda.py at the root level. There is no sub folder in the underlying folder like python_data_collector/python_data_collector. So this doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: My zip command in shell is as such: zip -r artifact/code.zip python_data_collector/

Comment: I guess that command will copy the folder recursively (given the -r), which implies that it will also copy the `python_data_collector` folder itself. You might have better luck with a `zip -r artifact/code.zip python_data_collector/*` but you should test and check since I don't know the behaviour of the zip command by heart.